# ERROR : When trying deployment of model in ML I get-'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, numpy, machine-learning, streamlit

I have used the below code for my python streamlit deployment of ML Model.

```
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


similarity=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\nikso\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\similarity.pkl','rb'),buffers=None)
list=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\nikso\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\movies_dict.pkl','rb'),buffers=None)
movies=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list)


def recomm(movie):
  mov_index=movies[movies['title']==movie].index[0]
  sim=similarity[mov_index]
  movlist=sorted(list(enumerate(sim)),reverse=True,key=lambda x:x[1])[1:6]
  
  rec_movie=[]
  for i in movlist:
    # print(i[0])
    rec_movie.append(movies.iloc[i[0]]['title'])
  return rec_movie

st.title('Movie Recommender System')

selected_movie_name = st.selectbox(
     'How would you like to be contacted?',
     movies['title'].values)

if st.button('Recommend'):
     recom=recomm(selected_movie_name)
     # recom=np.array(recom)
     for i in recom:
        st.write(i)
```

On colab the code is working fine but on vscode it was showing this error.

```
File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\Streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\app.py", line 30, in <module>
    recom=recomm(selected_movie_name)
File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\app.py", line 15, in recomm
    movlist=sorted(list(enumerate(sim)),reverse=True,key=lambda x:x[1])[1:6]
```

Now I had to use different IDEs for deployement. But when I removed the keyword 'list' in the given line 15 it worked fine. What can be the reason behind it? I am ca begineer and really curious about it. Thank you.

Comment: All I can tell is that the two environments seem to be using different versions of Python and/or pandas.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I removed the keyword 'list' in the given line 15 it worked fine. What can be the reason behind it?

TL;DR: `sorted` accepts iterables, and `enumerate` is already an iterable

Long answer:

When you define `list` as

```py
list=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\nikso\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\movies_dict.pkl','rb'),buffers=None)
```

you're overriding Python's built-in `list` type. Python lets you do this without issuing any warnings, but the result is that, in your script, `list` now represents a dictionary object. The result of this is that when you call `list(enumerate(sim))` later on, *you're treating your dictionary object as a callable*, which it is not.

The solution? Avoid overriding Python built-ins whenever you can.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


similarity=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\nikso\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\similarity.pkl','rb'),buffers=None)
movies_dict=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\nikso\OneDrive\Desktop\mlproject\movies_dict.pkl','rb'),buffers=None)
movies=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movies_dict)


def recomm(movie):
  mov_index=movies[movies['title']==movie].index[0]
  sim=similarity[mov_index]
  movlist=sorted(list(enumerate(sim)),reverse=True,key=lambda x:x[1])[1:6]
  
  rec_movie=[]
  for i in movlist:
    # print(i[0])
    rec_movie.append(movies.iloc[i[0]]['title'])
  return rec_movie

st.title('Movie Recommender System')

selected_movie_name = st.selectbox(
     'How would you like to be contacted?',
     movies['title'].values)

if st.button('Recommend'):
     recom=recomm(selected_movie_name)
     # recom=np.array(recom)
     for i in recom:
        st.write(i)
```

To answer *specifically* why removing "list" on line 15 seemed to fix the issue, though: `sorted` accepts iterables, and `enumerate` is already an iterable. All `list` is doing on line 15 is gathering the results of `enumerate` before passing them into `sorted`. But the *fundamental reason* why removing `list` fixed things is because you're overriding Python's built-in, which you probably want to avoid doing.